# Charge Induction on Spherical Cavity

Tags: electrostatics, charge

If there is a spherical conducting shell which has charges $+Q$ and $-Q$ placed inside at two locations (can be any two locations). will there be no net charge induced on the inner surface of the cavity irrespective of the locations of the charges as long as the net charge placed inside the cavity is zero?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. The total amount of induced charge on the inner surface of the shell will equal -1 times the total charge in the cavity, so in your scenario, that would be zero.

To prove this, draw a Gaussian surface that lies entirely within the shell's material, so that it completely encloses the inner surface of the shell. Since the surface lies within the material, which is a conductor, the electric field is zero on the surface. By Gauss's law, the total charge enclosed by this surface (which is the amount of induced charge on the inner surface plus the amount of charge in the cavity) must be zero. Another consequence we immediately see from this analysis is that if any additional charge is placed on the shell, it goes entirely to the outer surface.